# linq to entities C# Group By / Distinct query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Linq to Entity query that pulls out photos of my database. My ultimate goal is just to get the size and sum them up but I need to do a distinct call on the ID first because I am grouping the call and obviously there could be multiple records with the same photo size so I cant call distinct on that. So how would I call a distinct on the photoID but pull the photo size? thanks for any help.

```
from x in _context.Clients
join media in _context.Mediae 
on x.ID equals media.ClientID into Medias
from submedia in Medias.DefaultIfEmpty()
group new { x.ClientName, submedia } by new { x.ClientName } into g

//I would like to get the Sum of the MediaSize out of this But I call distinct on ID                       
let mediaCount = g.Where(x=>x.submedia  != null).Select(x=>x.submedia .ID).Distinct()
//Example of what I wish would work below
//g.Where(x => x.subEventMedia != null).Select(x => x.subEventMedia.ID).Distinct().Sum(x => x.subEventMedia.MediaSize)
```

Comment: by "Photo Size" do you mean the count of `Mediae` by `ClientName`? I don't see photo size in your query.

Comment: There is a property on subEventMedia called MediaSize, I would like to sum those all up. I edited my code a little to give you an example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why you did outer join and select `Where(x=>x.submedia  != null)` after?

Comment: @yD1m, I cut out most of the code. Not relevant, sorry for any confustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and the select the first item in that group to get the effect of a `DistinctBy`.

```
let mediaCount = g.Where(x=>x.submedia != null)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.submedia.ID)
    .Sum(mediaGroup => mediaGroup.FirstOrDefault().submedia.MediaSize)
```

Comment: So will get a list of all the media? or the first 1. I need the sum of all, not the first

Comment: @user516883 You said you want to get the distinct items by ID, and then sum those distinct items.  That's what this does.  It doesn't get just one, it gets one size value for each unique ID.

Comment: My understanding of distinct is removing duplicates. I want a distinct list of PhotoIDs from my query, but my goal is to get the media sizes.

Comment: @user516883 Yes, and this does exactly that, it just doesn't use the `Distinct` method because `Distinct` doesn't accept a keyselector, which is what you really want.

Comment: Ok let me try it out. Thanks!

Comment: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead

Comment: @user516883 Did you consider using `FirstOrDefault` instead?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! I still dont understand how all the media is distinct and also, and it looks like Sum(mediaGroup => mediaGroup.FirstOrDefault()) could be a possible null, is there a way to check for that

Comment: @user516883 It's *not* possible for `FirstOrDefault` to be null here; if there are no items with a given ID there will be no group created for it; you *know* that all groups have at least one item in them, which is why I originally used `First`.